# Why downvotes on comments are not considered in U&L?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to inquire and suggest the following:

1- **Inquiry:** Yes, it is weird! There is only an upvote button on the comments! Why downvotes on the comments were not considered?

2- **Suggest:** including a downvote button on the comments is vital! I read many inappropriate comments here and there. Some People just have big ego, others are disrespectful, some users are not cooperative enough with other users (especially the newbies). Including a down voting button on the commanets and link it probably to the total number of reputations (for example every two down votes on a comment would elemnitae 5 reputations from the total score) would improve, significantly, the quality of the comments –scientifically and ethically.

I know that somebody will say that you can *flag* a comment. This is correct, but this is not enough to improve the quality of the comments.

Comment: related on SE meta: [*How does comment voting and flagging work*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) and [*Allow downvoting comments*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments)

Comment: @ sebasth. Thank you. It is strange that the links you had provided are nine years old. Nothing was considered about ti?!

Comment: and in [2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152214/307535) and in [2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171677/307535) and in [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244222/307535) ...

Comment: Someone more authoritative than me would have to confirm, but this sort of feature is likely Stack-wide; not sure, particularly given the latest theming change, that they could add this to *just* U&L.

Comment: You can always choose whether your prefer people commenting and true feedback for your questions, or whether you want to impose informal and self-censorship by the community, and people will just downvote instead of commenting.  As for "newbies", I know a 100-2000 user is a newbie, as for your tipycal Joe "help me, I am a newbie"/Kali drive-by user, I do not know whether he has posted 1 time or 200 times here, and that is clearly a problem that SE is ignoring for inflating the numbers of the user base here.

Comment: If you listen to the original podcasts that went along with the creation of stackoverflow Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky debated this and Jeff's position was always that the comments weren't meant to live forever w/ the A'ers, they were merely a mechanism to help the author shape it. This is why they have smaller fonts and don't have a lot of focus brought to them. Flagging is how you deal w/ any issues w/ comments.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest flagging these kinds of comments:

> - inappropriate comments
> - others are disrespectful

... and possibly these:

> - some users are not cooperative enough with other users (especially the newbies).

... and this is just unclear:

> Some People just have big ego

Given the long history of status-declined for downvoting comments and their second-class citizen status, my suggestion would be flagging, positive comments, or invitations to chat.

Comment: thank you Jeff. When we talk about adding or removing a feature, there should be an objective. The most important question is : adding or removing a feature (e.g. downvoting, flagging) how this will improve the quality of the comments? This is the most important question from my perspectives! if I know that my comment will be downvoted and this will remove from my reputations, or badges, or lower my status.... I will make the effort to make great participation.On the other side, why not upvitng add to the user's reputations total score!